# Azure DevOps Pipeline Azure File Copy Failing

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

My Azure DevOps Pipeline is getting the following error (actual values switched for security):

> ##[error]Upload to container: 'XXXXXXXX' in storage account: 'YYYYYY' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with
> non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.' For more
> info please refer to https://aka.ms/azurefilecopyreadme

This is occurring during this step:

```
  - task: AzureFileCopy@5
    displayName: Copy Files to CDN Origin
    inputs:
      SourcePath: 'wwwroot/*'
      azureSubscription: 'aaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeee'
      Destination: 'AzureBlob'
      storage: 'YYYYYY'
      ContainerName: 'XXXXXXXX'
```

The following roles are assigned in IAM:

[image]

What am I missing here?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ##[error]Upload to container: 'XXXXXXXX' in storage account: 'YYYYYY' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.'

You can refer to the following points to resolve the issue.

1.The AzureFilecopy task is using the Service Principal to access the Storage account. So you need to grant the **Storage Blob Data Owner** and **Storage Blob Data Contributor** to Service Principal instead of personal account.

Refer to the steps to confirm the Service Principal:

Step1: Navigate to **Azure DevOps -> Project Settings -> Service Connections-> Find the service connection**. Click the option: **Manage Service Principal** and confirm the Service Principal information.

[image]

Step2:You can grant the Storage Blob Data Owner and Storage Blob Data Contributor role to the service principal in Storage account.

2.You can downgrade the AzureFileCopy task to **version 3** and then upload the files to Storage account.

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  displayName: 'AzureBlob File Copy'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: 'wwwroot/*'
    azureSubscription: xx
    Destination: AzureBlob
    storage: xx
    ContainerName: xx
    sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: 240
```

When you use AzureFileCopy@3, you don't need to add additional permission to service principal.

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help.  The multiple screens for IAM (one for subscription, one for the resource) is a bit weird and threw me off.   But now it appears to be working with the 'Step 2'

Answer (score 1):

I have just test at my side, all works well for me. code is alomost identical with you.

```
steps:
- task: AzureFileCopy@5
  inputs:
    SourcePath: 'test.yml'
    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'wbsatest'
    ContainerName: 'wbcontainertest'
  name: AzureFileCopy
```

**my role:**

1. a service principal already have **Owner** at subscription level.(you may use **"Storage Account Contributor"** instead). *--- Based Role*
2. I add an addidtional role **"Storage Blob Data Contributor"** ---- *Additional Role*

> warning: I don't test the "Based Role" affects here (I donot want to delete service principal from owner), but when I missing the "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role, occur the sample error message as you.

**suggestion:**

if you have suffit permission at the subscription, simply add the **Owner role** to the service principal (it's brute) or **Storage Account Contributor Role**. hope my test help you.

[image]