Upload files to Azure Storage with Azure Devops Pipeline. cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \\?\D:\a\1\s\drop\editor-docs
I configured the Azure Devops Pipeline with a AzureFileCopy@5 / 6 task. I am trying to upload the Pipeline.Workspace/drop/folder name/ to the storage account.
The log confuses me :
Uploading files from source path: 'D:\a\1\s\drop\editor-docs)' to storage account: storageaccountname
But in the next line I am receiving the error cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path \?\D:\a\1\s\drop\editor-docs.
I also tried it with Powershell, but with Powershell I was not able to pass the path as a parameter and that causes the script failing with the error "the parameter ... is not recognized as a cmdlet".
How can I upload the artifact to Azure Storage?
Changing the VM to Windows did not help for me.
Build.yml
jobs:
- job: 
  pool: 
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseRubyVersion@0
    displayName: Use Ruby >= 2.4

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy Folder Armtemplates
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'armtemplates'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/armtemplates'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy Folder Pipelines
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'pipelines'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/pipelines'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy Folder Scripts
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'scripts'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/scripts'

  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/scripts/InstallJekyll.sh'
      workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/editor-docs'
    displayName: Install Jekyll and bundler
      

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Copy Folder _site
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: 'editor-docs/_site'
      TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/editor-docs'


  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifact To Pipeline'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
      artifact: 'drop'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'

Deploy.yml I tried also : SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/editor-docs/)'
jobs:
  - job: DeployStaticWebsite
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - download: current
      artifact: drop

    - task: AzureFileCopy@5
      displayName: Upload Web Files To Storage
      inputs:
        SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/drop/editor-docs/)'
        azureSubscription: TestSubscriptionStorageAccount
        Destination: 'AzureBlob'
        storage: '$(StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp)'
        ContainerName: 'test'


Share your YAML.


error cannot start job due to error: cannot scan the path ?\D:\a\1\s\drop\editor-docs

Based on the error message and the yaml sample, the cause of the issue is that you are using the wrong path variable in the AzureFileCopy task.
The $(Build.SourcesDirectory) will point to the path: D:\a\1\s. But the artifacts will be download to $(Pipeline.Workspace) (D:\a\1).
To solve this issue, you need to use the path $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/editor-docs/ in the Azurefilecopy task.
For example:
- task: AzureFileCopy@5
  displayName: Upload Web Files To Storage
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/editor-docs/'
    azureSubscription: TestSubscriptionStorageAccount
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: '$(StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp)'
    ContainerName: 'test'

On the other hand, if the build and deploy pipeline are two independent pipelines, you need to specify specific build information in the download artifacts task.
For example:
jobs:
  - job: DeployStaticWebsite
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
      inputs:
        buildType: 'specific'
        project: 'projectname'
        definition: 'definitionname'
        buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
        artifactName: 'drop'
        targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

    - task: AzureFileCopy@5
      displayName: Upload Web Files To Storage
      inputs:
        SourcePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/drop/editor-docs/'
        azureSubscription: TestSubscriptionStorageAccount
        Destination: 'AzureBlob'
        storage: '$(StorageAccountNameStaticWebApp)'
        ContainerName: 'test'

For more detailed info, you can refer to the doc: Use predefined variables and DownloadPipelineArtifact@2 - Download Pipeline Artifacts v2 task

Let me try it now. I will come back to you shortly. Thank you

No problem. Feel free to let me know the result.

@Sergio An additional message: The Azure file copy task can be used in Windows Agent only. In the deploy job, you need to change the ubuntu-latest agent to windows-latest agent

I have changed the Sourcepath from /drop/editor-docs to /editor-docs and added the download pipeline task as you said. It is seeing now the files (total 53) and is trying to upload. Now I am getting the error Authentication failed, it is either not correct, or expired, or does not have the correct permission. The service principal has contributor permissions on subscription level.

@Sergio It seems that the issue in the ticket has been resolved. The latest issue is related to the permission in the Azure Storage account, you can refer to my ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77624088/13464420 , you need to grant the Storage Blob Data Owner and Storage Blob Data Contributor to Service Principal. Or you can downgrade the Azure file copy task to version 3
